# Regarding char arrays, I'm trying to assign each character in my array to another value

Tags: c++

Thanks for taking the time to look at my post. I'm relatively new to programming and have a question regarding character array(s)

The idea is a very basic encrypt / decrypt

Say I have an array called "key"

```
char key​ [26​]={​'B'​,'A'​,'D'​,'C'​,'F'​,'E'​,'H'​,'G'​,'J'​,'I'​,'L'​,'K'​,'N'​,'M'​,'P'​,'O'​,'R'​,'Q'​,'T'​,'S'​,'V'​,'U'​,'X'​,'W'​,'Z'​,'Y'​};
```

Once I pass the key value into a method that is supposed to alter the value of each individual ASCII value to:

A = B, B = A, D = C, C = D, etc.

Can you point me in the right direction as far as the approach I would need to take to return the decrypted value.

Thanks~

Comment: We don't write code to spec here.  You'll need to take a crack at it and show us your code if you get stuck or have a problem more specific than "Here are my requirements."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint to get you started.  Start with a simple C function that takes an array of characters and it's length:

```
void encode_characters(char* key, int length)
{
    // your code goes here    

}
```

Your code within that function will do the swapping of items in the array passed in. Then you can invoke it from within your program as follows:

```
char key​[26​] = {​'B'​,'A'​,'D'​,'C'​,'F'​,'E'​,'H'​,'G'​,'J'​,'I'​,'L'​,'K'​,'N'​,'M'​,'P'​,'O'​,'R'​,'Q'​,'T'​,'S'​,'V'​,'U'​,'X'​,'W'​,'Z'​,'Y'​};
encode_characters(key, 26);
```